# Should I give up on the dream of ever making it in the science industry

Tags: interviewing, job-search

So recently I received a standard no response rejection mail(in which it was mentioned that I don't have multiple years of experience). Based on this and other negative interview experiences(where one recruiter was kind enough to mention "some people know a certain technology some don't and you belong to latter), should I give up on my dream of making it in the science industry?

A side note: I spent 6 years gaining two masters one for the purpose of theoretical  enhancement and one for practical enhancement and I did a lot of side projects of which I AM EXTREMELY PROUD OF.

Comment: So your basic question is "How do I gain experience in a field where I have no experience?"

Comment: So you did two masters, but then apply to a job you do not know the requisite technology for. It seems you're not applying for jobs matching your qualifications. I think I would need more detail to give you useful advice.

Comment: Have you looked at graduate jobs in the science field? It's not exactly where you want to be I understand but you can't simply get into a high level job with 0 experience

Comment: We simply can't tell you, based on this information, as to whether you're lacking any fundamental skills / experience or not to make it into this industry. It could even be something as simple as bad interview technique.

Comment: Twyxz, your point is spot on correct, even I agree that for engineering jobs where safety is of paramount importance,0 experience will simply not cut it.

Comment: @SparshGarg: even when safety is paramount, there **is** room for beginners. Of course, they will not get to do the most critical detail, but there **is** a chance for them. I worked for 18+ years in embedded real-time software development (programming, requirements, architecture, project management, process improvement...). But first job was with Siemens automotive (currently part of Continental), when I had no experience. Bottom line: do not expect to work from the beginning with the top scientists. Be patient and work your way up.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, I am working to join some small text files into a big one (it is the truth). I AM EXTREMELY PROUD OF THAT! Does that make me a scientist? Does it mean that I have experience?

Self-pride is good sometimes, but the industry, any industry, has different needs. During school (university included), you only learn how to learn. The real learning begins after you finish school - it is the hard truth.

So:

1. No, do not give up your dream.
2. No, do not expect to get to the top in a heart beat. It may take many years.
3. Keep an open mind. You may discover that what you chased at the beginning is not what you actually wanted.
4. Learn, learn, learn. Anything, anywhere.
5. Learn to understand. Just storing information in the brain will not cut it. Build the ability to expand on what you already have.

Comment: you are welcome. Just a small note: your success does not always depend on you. Always be prepared for failure. Always have spare plans, spare goals in your life. In this way, you will sometimes be disappointed, but even better, you will still have reasons to enjoy life. I wish you success! Do not give up! https://veryfunnypics.eu/128/